# "ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape" when one-hot encoding DNA sequence

Tags: python, data-science, dna-sequence

I'm getting this ValueError while I am applying one hot encoding on variable length DNA sequence.

Steps followed so far:

1. Changed variable length to fixed length with zero padding.
2. Tried strip as well but same error.

Sample code:

Note: The code which says `print(one_hot_encoded.toarray().shape) )`,  length of an array shows same but still getting the error. Not sure what else is missing here.

```
for sequence in sequences:
    integer_encoded = integer_encoder.fit_transform(list(sequence.strip()))
    integer_encoded = np.array(integer_encoded).reshape(-1, 1)
    one_hot_encoded = one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded)
    input_features.append(one_hot_encoded.toarray())
    print(one_hot_encoded.toarray().shape)
```

Anyone have pointers here?

Comment: Please show the complete traceback of the error.

Comment: This error shows because of the change in the shape. Can you change the shape and give a try

Comment: I doubt that the block of code you are showing yields that error. It might have to do with `np.stack` or something. Please include those code blocks as well (and also the full traceback as requested)...

Comment: np.set_printoptions(threshold=40)
--->  input_features = np.stack(input_features)
       print("Example sequence\n-------------")
       print('DNA Sequence #1:\n',sequences[0][:10],'...',sequences[0][-10:])

<__array_function__ internals> in stack(*args, **kwargs)

~/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py in stack(arrays, axis, out)
        shapes = {arr.shape for arr in arrays}
        if len(shapes) != 1:
--> raise ValueError('all input arrays must have the same shape')
     result_ndim = arrays[0].ndim + 1
ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape